# SQLAlchemy: KeyError when looping through model objects in order to copy them

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to query rows and copy them while changing an attribute of each. Here's my code.

```
 colObjs= db.session.query(Column).filter_by(chart_id=oldChartID).all()
 for colObj in colObjs:
   make_transient(colObj)
   print colObj.id
   del colObj.id
   colObj.chart_id= newChartID
   db.session.add(colObj)
   db.session.commit()
```

In this example, `colObjs` has two objects. I loop thru `colObjs`, going over each `colObj`. The first item in the loop copies fine. But when I try copying the second one, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/path/to/myApp.py", line 859, in copyGraphic
    del colObj.id
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 227, in __delete__
    self.impl.delete(instance_state(instance), instance_dict(instance))
  File "/path/to/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 679, in delete
    del dict_[self.key]
KeyError: 'id'
```

Furthermore, the output of the `print` statement on the first item of the loop shows the `coloObj` id, but the second one outputs `None`.

Why does this error happen? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the exception is that you commit in the loop. All in all that's usually an antipattern. After first round [the act of committing will expire the `Column` instances](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#committing) that were in the session previously, so in the 2nd iteration `del colObj.id` raises, because the object has been expired and there's no loaded state. The solution is to simply move the commit after the loop.